# How to debug a javascript error in a rails project?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a project and am trying to incorporate a purchased theme into the project.

The theme comes with 3 javascript files: mvpready-core.js, mvpready-landing.js, mvpready-helpers.

I copied the js files into the `assets/javascript` folder and then added them to `application.js` like so:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require mvpready-core
//= require mvpready-landing
//= require mvpready-helpers
//= require_tree .
```

When I load the web page I get the following errors in console:
In the mvready-core file

```
SyntaxError: illegal character
book
```

In mvpready-landing file

```
ReferenceError: mvpready_core is not defined
mvpready_core.navHoverInit ({ delay: { show: 250, hide: 350 } })
```

I have tried switching the order of the files in application.js but that didn't help.

Here is the js of the static theme without rails:

```
<!-- Core JS -->
<script src="../../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- App JS -->
<script src="../../global/js/mvpready-core.js"></script>
<script src="../../global/js/mvpready-helpers.js"></script>
<script src="./js/mvpready-landing.js"></script>
```

and here it is with rails:

```
<!-- Core JS -->
    <script src="/assets/jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-8e98a7a072a6cee1372d19fff9ff3e6aa1e39a37d89d6f06861637d061113ee7.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/transition.self-db278e3a8fa6249c16796b113ebd29e11ef4e2cd021618ed84895d524a4511e0.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/alert.self-ebce91ec66c71bcee451ea7da9128fd1bf8faa02c6d22ea04c598423431e4c08.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/modal.self-ab1767545e27c0dbd36971e656ae4927171f673e3d932cdec2cbef39e991952b.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/dropdown.self-8bb9309b6c24a4ba6b94026a049d25b13bdc0553b6fe83255c14a715ba624cc4.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-bd0c6724cdc75302fe98dfeff923112b76c1673cf4a0752a7050b7feea15594c.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tab.self-7e3ee4a243bb416b5f0111a0be08f8547c5d72ba71fe4afe4a4a007f5cb4e10e.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/tooltip.self-d7f9330825307d053f68da11bb9ddc9b070df72deef3d115f2f3d55f66b17457.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/popover.self-cd672ecad3b549e1dbd89bfd044e5812d6fdade56f42d48e3acee0c3f4614526.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/button.self-ceb562de883e04359bb2c06f07bdf6ecf065cc8a5027e2e58857c5e91b0b68e3.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/collapse.self-a87553101c955a01e2e8c81fad69a16582ddbf58fe95d5eb335dde5567af7647.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/carousel.self-5d09995e01b647168888180d40e271f9a6759d68ae7ac029d7026af58813d376.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap/affix.self-14e04bbe71282aa039322ab93e3a3a886ddede5f59a2f365f7c861f697bbeb21.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery.color.self-563ece6445847ae2087fffbe72b094918ea69e3124d0389b2819fa5400a96210.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/mvpready-landing.self-e43f32f1c40792b294dfc7cfda1ae60af108443c2dbce31e8612acb5fdc75ddb.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/mvpready-core.self-f0da2b30dbdf9f447bd037b448e4e56201d93885a2fa14ea75992ab0cc3186e1.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/mvpready-helpers.self-05f3feaf1e237e0850478afaa5a5aa595e0950f54ac10a148d4288d32f5259df.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/bootstrap.self-803d1c88e207632a77fa3967407fbea537d48e6f7f54470e6a2ee8f14a7aefa9.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.self-968f575d6d917a8150cf2e95fd6ec791beb39f9c32f85283e7a09b9d8534333a.js?body=1"></script>
```

Comment: If you copied js files to `assets/` dir then `//= require_tree .` will include them by default. Try removing it or explicit `require`.

Answer (score 1):

The core-file of the theme has a syntax-error in it, you can't fix this by changing the order of the files. Contact the creator of the theme.

Comment: @spuggy, if I am at your place, I would  compare the source generated by rails to your static working files.

Comment: @maximus thanks for the help. I've added the js for rails and the static them. Maybe that could help?

Comment: @spuggy if you compare, the order of inclusion is different when rails. Rearranging the `require` statements to match with static files should work.